# Not outputting expected value in simple assignment

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

When I assign some value to a variable with four bits, I get an unexpected result when I simply output the value. I have never seen this before and was wondering if I'm doing something wrong syntactically.

```
module main;   
     reg [3:0] x;   
     initial 
     begin
         $monitor("%b",x);
         x=0010;
     end 
endmodule
```

I get an output of `1010`. However, I expected to get an output of `0010`.

Comment: You are getting the right value: 10 (decimal) or as you wrote it 0010 decimal.

Comment: I expected %b to return the binary value in monitor though. Also why might it print two 10's?

Comment: No, it prints out 10 (decimal) in  binary that is 0b1010 as you gave it decimal: 0010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verilog interprets your number as decimal since you did not specify a base.  The number `0010` in your Verilog code is decimal ten (10), which is `1010` in binary format.  `x=0010` is the same as `x=10`. You need to add a binary base specifier.  Change:

```
     x=0010;
```

to:

```
     x='b0010;
```